# Appium test result file

Tags: continuous-integration, appium, bamboo

I am building a CI pipeline with Bamboo and I run automated tests using Appium. I have successfully run the Appium server and test scripts but I would like to have results in for example xml file so I could pass it to Bamboo. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

it might be a bit late to respond on your question, but I'm using Appium with node.js and mocha to write my tests. To create a proper xml with the results I'm doing:

```
mocha --recursive -R xunit test/ > test-reports.xml
```

(test/ is the folder containing all my test files). This is generating a proper xml. I haven't tested it with Bamboo but I assume it's capable of reading XUnit test reports.